# Finite expectation

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be i.i.d with mean $\mu$. Let $T$ be a stopping time with respect to $X_,X_2,...$ with $E(T)<\infty$. Show that $E\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |X_n|I\{T\ge n\}\right)<\infty$.

My idea is  $E\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |X_n|I\{T\ge n\}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(|X_n|I\{T\ge n\})$ and if I am able to prove that $|X_n| \le K$ where K is non zero constatnt, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(|X_n|I\{T\ge n\})\le K\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\{T\ge n\})=KE(T)<\infty$. But I am not sure whether my claim is true. Can anyone give me any hints in solving this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $ I \{ T \geq n \}) =  1 - I \{ T \leq n-1 \}) $. Now, $ T $ is a stopping time, hence the event $ \{ T \leq n-1 \} \in {\cal F}_{n-1} := \sigma ( X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_{n-1}) $. Thus, $ I \{ T \geq n \}) $ is $ {\cal F}_{n-1} $ measurable. Since $ X_n $ is independent of $ X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_{n-1} $, we have $ X_n $ is independent of $ {\cal F}_{n-1} $. Thus, for any $ n \geq 1 $, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \bigl( |X_n| I \{ T \geq n\} \bigr) & =  \mathbb{E} \Bigl( \mathbb{E} \bigl( |X_n| I \{ T \geq n \} \mid {\cal F}_{n-1} \bigr) \Bigr) \\
& =  \mathbb{E} \Bigl( I \{T \geq n\} \mathbb{E} \bigl(  |X_n|  \mid {\cal F}_{n-1} \bigr) \Bigr) \\
& =  \mathbb{E} \Bigl( I \{T \geq n\} \mathbb{E} \bigl(  |X_n|  \bigl) \Bigr) \\
& =  \beta \mathbb{E} \bigl( I \{T \geq n\} \bigr) = \beta \mathbb{P} \bigl( T \geq n\bigr) 
\end{align*}
where $ \beta = \mathbb{E}( |X_n| ) $.

Thus, $ \mathbb{E} \Bigl(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |X_n| I \{ T \geq n \} \Bigr) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E} \Bigl(  |X_n| I \{T \geq n \} \Bigr) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \beta \mathbb{P} ( T \geq n) = \beta \mathbb{E} (T) $.

Comment: Are you making the assumption that $E(|X_n|)=\mu$?